Distinguishing poles and zeros in winding number calculation
I am trying to develop a numerical algorithm for finding the roots of a generic complex function $f(z)$ using winding numbers. This is done by dividing the desired complex domain into "boxes" whose edges form the contours to be mapped through $f(z)$. If $f(z)$ has only zeros with no poles, the problem is straightforward; the winding number of $f(z)$ on each box is the number of zeros contained inside the box.
If, however, $f(z)$ has both poles and zeros, it becomes necessary to somehow exclude the poles  while remaining agnostic to the form of $f(z)$. The general argument principle says
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C g(z) \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}dz = \sum_i n(C,z_i) g(z_i) - \sum_i n(C,p_i) g(p_i),
\end{equation}
where $z_i$ and $p_i$ are the zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside of the contour. To exclude the poles, I thought of using
\begin{equation}
g(z) = \exp{\left[ -|f(z)|^2 \right] }.
\end{equation}
Thus, all $g(p_i) \rightarrow 0$ and $g(z_i) \rightarrow 1$. However, this function violates the requirements for $g(z)$ to satisfy the general argument principle (and thus it gives the wrong answer).
Finally, my question: is there a way to salvage this $g(z)$? If not, is there another way to discriminate between the number of zeros and poles contained inside a contour?

It seems to me that for any analytic function we encounter in practice, we would be very aware of where the poles are before we start any more detailed analysis....

I would typically be working with very complicated and unwieldy functions. While in principle I could indeed determine the list of poles, I was hoping for a more agnostic solution.
